# How can I resolve the Django error "add a non-nullable field"?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting an error regarding a Django model when I try to run `makemigrations`:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'person' to owner without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
> Please select a fix:
>
> 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
> 2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

I am using Django 1.8 and this is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User)
    alphanumeric    = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='hanya yang mengandung karakter alphanumeric')
    email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', unique=True, max_length=244)
    username        = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth   = models.DateTimeField()
    date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD      = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS     = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        fullname = self.first_name+" "+self.last_name
        return self.fullname

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def list_operator(self):
        return self.operators.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Operator(models.Model):
    person          = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="operators", null=True)
    alphanumeric    = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='hanya yang mengandung karakter alphanumeric')
    email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', unique=True, max_length=244)
    username        = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username;
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code isn't wrong. Just follow the instructions provided by the message...

The `person` field within your `Operator` model can't be `null` (because `null=True` isn't set). You must already have Operators in your database, so Django doesn't know what to do with those.

You need to either: (a) provide a `default` value in your model, (b) provide a default during the migration process, or (c) enable `null` values for that field.

Comment: i already edit field username and provide null = True, blank=True but it same error. why? *you can see in above, i already edit.

Comment: `username` isn't the issue. `person` is the issue (the field)

Comment: so you meant i put null=True like this person          = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="operators", null=True). right?

Comment: Yes, that's an option.

Comment: Are those all of your models?

Comment: no, you can see my full model in this link http://pastebin.com/LfRbXAE9 . i already edit all of field person but it same error. why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80745/discussion-between-apsi-and-rnevius).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have `null=True` property in your model or set a FK instance manually which isn't a simple task sometimes, you can do the following:

1. Delete all instances of `Person` and `Operator` models from your DB (e.g. using `DjangoAdmin`).
2. Set `null=True` of the FK field of your child model (field `person` of model `Operator` in your case).
3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`.
4. Delete `null=True` property from p. 2.
5. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` again.
6. When running `makemigrations` from p. 5, you need to choose `2) Ignore for now. Existing rows that contain NULL values will have to be handled manually, for example with a RunPython or RunSQL operation`.
7. Run `python manage.py migrate`.

The main downside of the method is that you have to delete all instances of at least two your models which isn't always acceptable. However, I'm sure if it isn't your case, this is the best way to solve the error.